# How to repair my fuse panel

Tags: electrical

I want to replace a block in my fuse panel that broke when I pulled a fuse holder out. I have placed my method alongside a pic of the panel. I am wondering if this seems reasonable to do or if I am missing something I may have to remove also. There is no wiring connected to that block at all. Thanks[image]

Comment: Would you consider upgrading to a breaker panel? I know it doesn't directly address your question, but if you're gonna replace/fix something, you might as well make it better.

Comment: I was going to (have 100amp service, all I need) and the Power Co Insp came out and said they would have to upgrade to 200amp and install a new mast up through my eave. I could afford the 100amp breaker panel but not this complete upgrade. I just redid 1/2 my roof and still have the other 1/2 to do. So this why I am just repairing this panel. I don't even require that side right now but want to make it right.

Comment: @RWHobbs -- where are you on this planet?  The power company shouldn't be *requiring* a service upgrade for a main panel changeout at like-for-like ampacity...

Comment: Also, how are you even planning to get replacement parts, and how big is the box (both circuits and physical height * width * depth)?

Comment: I'm in Halifax, N.S. I may have got a weird inspector, so after 6 months if I don't get them in, I have to re-apply. I may do that and if I get the same guy and the same answer, I think I will take it higher. I already got the identical part along with 6 fuse holders and 24 fuses. Cost me $20.00! Plus I got a fused shut off box for my furnace, thrown in!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel they do it in our area too... They don't know anything less than 200 amp, the least expensive "cure" is a meter can with main breaker and swap the main breaker down to 100 (or 60 for a few)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel So does it look like I am on the right path to do the repair?

Comment: @RWHobbs -- I'm going to have to defer on this one

Comment: I don't blame you. I will take it very slow and easy and give it a try. I racked my brain looking at it for about 15 min at a time, about 6 times, and that is what I came up with. Won't be doing for at least a week so I'll leave this up for awhile anyway. If it works I will update with a big woohoo!

Comment: @RWHobbs Sorry, fuses aren't really my thing either, so the best I can say is invest in a multimeter. If nothing else, it'll help you avoid some nasty surprises.

Comment: @rwhobbs, it looks like your plan is sound. You should be able to do the repair without having to move the power over and then working on a partially live box. with the fridge & freezer left closed  they should be ok for 2 to 3 hours and this really should not take more than 30-60 minutes from what I see. I do repairs all the time but prefer a dead panel because you get focused on getting a part out then end up touching something live or dropping a screw that contacts a live part and a grounded part. I believe your plan will work but if done live invest an a pair of "hot gloves" for safety.

Comment: @EdBeal Thank you Ed. I was concerned it would take me too long, being an amateur at this. That is why I was hooking up the hot again, but shutting off the main each time I got my hands in there. I've never heard of "hot gloves". Will google them, but I will do it all at one time now that I know the fridge should be ok, and that will save me some steps and time. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Do you have any *multi-wire branch circuits* on the right-side fuses?   That is to say, do any of those circuits share a neutral?  *(that's a yes or no, we're *not* gonna get into the new rules about ganged shut-off on MWBCs, as that gets a little complicated where fuses are involved.)*  Also I respect fuses and I like the price, but the #1 reason to go circuit breakers is they don't make AFCI fuses.

Comment: @Harper I did have 2 of them, but I found the junction box where they split off and changed them to individual circuits.

Comment: Electrician "Hot gloves" are rubber gloves that provide insulation. Usually a pair of light welterweight leather gloves over the top to extend the life. Class 0 are good for 1000v  I am required to wear them a face shield and flash suit when working on energized equipment.

Comment: WOOHOO! Couldn't wait the week. The wife had to go babysit today so I didn't have to make her shut off her Facebook. Took a total of 40 min. All back to normal. Hardest part was getting the cross buss bars in properly.

Answer (score 1):

Done deal! Everything worked out fine.